# AS3 removing an event handler within a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I am adding an eventListener within the first function and wish to get rid of it in the second. Removing the eventListener doesn't seem to be working and as such each subsequent call to the first function is adding more event handlers. I know one way to get around this is to not add the eventListener within the function, but doing it this way will save me a lot of work for the rest of the code. Any ideas?

```
function errorBoxHandler(event:Event):void
{
    this.errorBox.errorOkBtn.addEventListener(
        MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, 
        function(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            errorBoxOkHandler(event, btnSelected, listIndexNum)
        }
    );
}

function errorBoxOkHandler(event:MouseEvent, btnSelected:String, listIndexNum:int):void
{    
    this.errorBox.errorOkBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, errorBoxOkHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are adding an anonymous function as a listener

```
    this.errorBox.errorOkBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, 
        function(event:MouseEvent){//here
           errorBoxOkHandler(event, btnSelected,listIndexNum)
    });
```

Adding `errorBoxOkHandler` directly as a listener like this:

```
this.errorBox.errorOkBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, errorBoxOkHandler);
```

will make it removable with the

```
this.errorBox.errorOkBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,errorBoxOkHandler);
```

call
*You will have to find a way to make `btnSelected` and `listIndexNum` visible from `errorBoxOkHandler` because as event listener it can accept only one argument*